# Функция преобразования каждой n подстроки из нижнего в верхний регистр?

Tags: c++

Проблема в том что я не понимаю как мне сделать функцию UpDownNPstr
особенно как мне возвращать из функции UpDownNPstr значения для вывода

Задание:
Функция int isLatin (char s) получает символ и определяет, является ли он символом латиницы (строчной или прописной буквой латинского алфавита).

Функция char* isPstrAlfabit (char* str, int& n) получает строку str и ищет в ней первую подстроку, содержащую только символы латиницы (строчные или прописные буквы латинского алфавита). Если такая подстрока найдена, функция возвращает через параметр по ссылке длину подстроки и ее адрес через возвращаемое значение, и 0 в противном случае. Используйте при разработке алгоритма функции функцию isLatin.

Функция int UpDown (char& s) получает через параметр по ссылке символьный объект, преобразует в нем, если это прописной буквенный символ в символ строчный и возвращает через возвращаемое значение 1, если преобразование сделано, и 0 в противном случае.

**Функция char* UpDownNPstr (char* str, int n) получает строку str и преобразует каждую n-ую подстроку латинских букв в подстроку тех же букв, но в коде верхнего регистра. Функция возвращает адрес строки str, если преобразования были осуществлены хотя бы над одной n-ой подстрокой строки str, и 0, если ни один символ в строке не был подвергнут преобразованию. Функция использует разработанные Вами функции isPstrAlfabit и UpDown.**

Программа со стандартного устройства ввода считывает число n и строку, и, используя функцию UpDownNPstr, преобразует строку, выдавая на экран только те из них, в которых удалось сделать преобразования. Программа подсчитывает количество строк, подвергшихся изменению.

```
int isLatin(char s)
{
    if(s>='a'&&s<='z'||s>='A'&&s<='Z')
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

char* isPstrAlfabit(char* str, int& n)
{
    int d=0, size=sizeof(str);
    char* Pstr;
    bool proov=false;

    n=0;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        if(isLatin(str[i])==1)
        {
            if(n==0)
            {
                Pstr+=str[i];
                proov=true;
                n=1;
            }
            else n++;
        }
        else if(proov==true) break;
    }
    return Pstr;
}


int UpDown(char& s)
{
    if(s>='A'&&s<='Z')
    {
        tolower(s);
        return 1;
    }
    else return 0;
}


char* UpDownNPstr(char* str,int n)
{
    ;((((((((
}

void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"RUS");
    string str;
    int n, choice;

    while(true)
    {
        cout<<"Input STR"<<endl;
        cin>>str;
        cout<<"Input n"<<endl;
        cin>>n;
        char *chstr=new char[str.length()];
        strcpy(chstr,str.c_str());

        string ggstr;

        ggstr+=UpDownNPstr(chstr, n);

        for(int i=0; i<sizeof(ggstr);i++)
            cout<<ggstr[i]<<", ";

        cout<<"1-exit\n2-repeat"<<endl;
        cin>>choice;
        if(choice==1) break;
    }
}
```

Comment: 0 - это нулевой указатель - `NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вы используете в своем коде оператор `sizeof` по отношению к указателям на строки. Он не делает того, что вы ожидаете. Правильный способ получения размера строки это функция `strlen`.
2. В функции `isPstrAlfabit` у вас есть переменная `char* Pstr`. Что вы подразумеваете операцией `Pstr += str[i]`? (Причем к неинициализированной переменной).
3. Функция `tolower` принимает значение символа и **возвращает** значение этого символа в нижнем регистре. Т.е. в функции `UpDown` нужно исправить инструкцию: `s = tolower(s);` вместо `tolower(s);`

---

Реализация требуемой фунции `UpDownNPstr` и исправленные функции:

```
char* isPstrAlfabit(char* str, int& n)
{
    char* sub = str; // изначально указывает на начало строки
    int len = strlen(str); // узнаем размер строки
    n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i, ++str)
    // ++str - это смещение указателя на единицу
    {
        if (isLatin(*str)) // если встретилась латинница
        {
            if (n == 0) // если это первый латинский символ
                sub = str; // запоминаем начало подстроки
            ++n; // увеличиваем количество символов подстроки
        }
        else if (n != 0) // если не латинница и есть хотя бы один символ латинницы
        {
            break; // выходим
        }
    }
    return (n == 0 ? 0 : sub); // если символов нет, возвращаем нулевой указатель
    // если есть, возвращаем указатель на начало подстроки
}

int UpDown(char& s)
{
    if (s >= 'A' && s <= 'Z')
    {
        s = tolower(s); // !присвоили
        return 1;
    }
    else return 0;
}

char* UpDownNPstr(char* str, int n)
{
    char* current = str; // изначально начало строки
    int size = 0;  // будет хранить размер подстроки
    bool changed = false; // флаг, означающий было ли хоть одно изменение
    while (current != 0) // пока текущая подстрока не нулевая
    {
        size = 0; // обнуление размера
        for (int i = 0; i < n && current; ++i)
            current = isPstrAlfabit(current + size, size); // ищем каждую следующую подстроку от текущей
                                                           // при n повторах найдем n-ую подстроку от текущей
        if (current) // если поиск завершился успешный
        {
            changed = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i, ++current)
            {
                // если нужно вывести изменяемые строки добавляем
                cout << *current;
                UpDown(*current); // изменяем каждый символ подстроки
            }
        }
    }
    return (changed ? str : 0);
}
```

---

Также следует исправить ошибки в функции `main`:

```
getline(cin, str); // вместо cin >> str;
char* chstr = new char[str.length() + 1]; // не забыть + 1 для нуля-терминатора
char* s = UpDownNPstr(chstr, n);
// никаких дополнительный std::строк не нужно
// тем более не нужно неправильного использования оператора sizeof
```